# How do I implement the Type for ChartData<Ttype, Tdata, Tlabel>

Tags: chart.js, react-tsx, react-chartjs-2

```
export const data = {
    labels,
    datasets: [
        {
            label: 'Dataset 1',
            data: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
            fill: true,
            borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.5)',
        }
    ]
};

export function App() {
    return <Line options={options} data={data} />;
}
```

it says data is not type of ChartData<Ttype, Tdata, Tlabel>

How would I implement this? I looked into Tdata and Tlabel and have gotten more confused.
Ive also tried assigning data to data: ChartData<'line'> and it still doesnt work. What am I missing???

Comment: I verified that, *assuming `labels` is an array*, your `data` conforms to type `ChartData<'line', DefaultDataPoint<'line'>, unknown>` (which is `ChartData<'line'>`, which [appears](https://react-chartjs-2.js.org/faq/typescript/) to be the form that react-chartjs 2 uses).  We may get insights from the details of the typescript error message. In general on SO, it's a good practice to *quote* the error message in full (or truncate if unreasonably large), not describe it.